# Alternatives of “I guess he is Bunting”

Tags: sentence-choice

Can “I guess he is Bunting” be converted into these sentences?

- He is Bunting as I guess.
- He is Bunting by my guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is unidiomatic. You have probably heard or read the phrase, "as I guess**ed**," so let me imagine a situation in which that would be correct:

> A few minutes ago, I saw a man 50 meters away from me. He was too far away for me to know who it was, but I've been expecting Bunting, so I assumed the man was Bunting. It's a few minutes later now, and the man has walked toward me. Ah! He *is* Bunting, just as I guessed.

As you can see, this usage does not match your situation.

"by my guess" is somewhat idiomatic. It works the same as phrases like, "By my estimate." But it sounds very old-fashioned and provincial. I would expect to hear it in a movie about cowboys, pirates, or men who hunt vampires. I can't recommend it for everyday speech.

Comment: "As I guess" is fine if you are writing in Middle English - "What time the manciple his tale had ended,
The sun down from the south line had descended
So low that he was not, unto my sight,
Degrees full nine and twenty yet in height.
Four of the clock it was then, as I guess: " Chaucer _The Pardoner's Prologue_

Comment: @Michael Harvey, you know, I thought there was *something* familiar about the expression. Yeah, Chaucer was 40 years ago, and I think I got a C+, so not my best moment.